# Core Data Scalar error only on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've been testing primarily using iPhone 6, 6 plus, and iPad. Just tried my app today on the iPhone 5 simulator, and got a Core Data error.

> CoreData: error: Property 'setId:' is a scalar type on class 'AppName.EntityName' that does not match its Entity's property's scalar type.  Dynamically generated accessors do not support implicit type coercion.  Cannot generate a setter method for it

Now, there is no 'setId' object in my app, but of course the entity does have an 'ID' object, which is set as an int.

```
class Entity: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: Int
}
```

In the Core Data model, the attribute type is set to Integer64. That might be my problem, as I picked that without knowing what was best. I have other attributes in the model and class, but they are all strings.

Looking for both a fix and an explanation as to why this happens only on some devices, so I can learn!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If the Core Data type is Integer 64 then you should declare the property as `Int64` (or let Xcode create the managed object subclass).

`Int` can be 32 bit or 64 bit, depending on the processor architecture.

Alternatively, define the property as `NSNumber*` instead of a scalar property. Of course you have to take care that on a 32-bit platform the values do not exceed the range of `Int`.

Comment: I did let Xcode create the class, but then I added the ID later. Also, if I set the property to Int64, I have to convert throughout my code when I try to enter data to this property. Is there a way to instead make the model match Int?

Comment: @Tim: Core Data has only fixed sized integers(16, 32, 64 bit).

Comment: I see that. So there is no way to use Int throughout my code and then convert to one size on saving to CD? Definitely grateful for the clarifications, I was just looking for a more universal solution.

Comment: @Tim: You can define the property as `NSNumber *` instead of a scalar properly. The Swift compiler should do most conversions automagically. – I'm writing this on the phone, therefore I cannot provide more details at present.

Comment: NSNumber was the magic ingredient! I only had to change two functions that called for Int where I was supplying entity.id. Once those also looked for NSNumber, voila! If you add an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: NSNumber do the trick for me, just changing the type in the entity and now works in old devices (iPhone 4, 4s, 5)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can write your own setter/getter method that transforms the `Int` into a `NSNumber` instance and passes this on the the *primitive value*. E.g.:

```
private(set) var publicId: Int {
  get {
    self.willAccessValueForKey("publicId")
    let value = self.primitivePublicId.longValue
    self.didAccessValueForKey("publicId")
    return value
  }
  set {
    self.willChangeValueForKey("publicId")
    self.primitivePublicId = NSNumber(long: newValue)
    self.didChangeValueForKey("publicId")
  }
}
@NSManaged private      var primitivePublicId: NSNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to try a "Clean"! That fixed it for me even though I had deleted the app from my device.